# StAX XML Parser not escaping single quote (&apos;)

Tags: java, xml, parsing

We are using StAX parser to read the large XML files and strip off some of the elements/attributes and write the XML file

The source XML file is valid XML file i.e. have all XML Special characters(`<`,`>`,`'`,`"`,`&`) escaped with respective XML versions(`&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&apos;`, `&quot;`, `&amp;`)

When StaX parser writing these special characters in the output file it is escaping `<`,`>`,`&` characters but not`'`,`"` characters i.e in output file we can see the `'`,`"` characters, although the input file have its escaped versions

I have tried to replace using `String.replaceAll("'","&apos;")` method before sending the output to StaX parser `writeAttribute` method

But as StAX parser already escaping <,>,& character the output is showing as `&amp;apos;`

Can you let me kow is there any configuration/utiltity in StAX parser API to solve this issue in StAX parser?

Or, alternatively, any other suggestions to use another XML writer tool which solves this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Single quotes only need to be escaped if they occur in an attribute value enclosed by single quotes. There's not really any reason to escape them otherwise.

Comment: I agree: I don't see a "problem" in the question above. Everything works as specified.