# Writing entity references (quote,apostrophe) to xml file - java

Tags: java, xml, dom, transformer-model

I am writing a java program which writes an xml file as output. Now, there are certain node values in the xml which contain entity references like <, >, ' and ". Current output is something like this:

```
<Parent>
  <Child>&lt;'"</Child>
</Parent>
```

The output i require:

```
<Parent>
  <Child>&lt;&apos;&quot;</Child>
</Parent>
```

I read in the following post that maybe its not possible to do what I want:
[StAX XML Parser not escaping single quote (&apos;)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141413/stax-xml-parser-not-escaping-single-quote-apos)

But the system which reads this xml file requires all quotes and apostrophes to be escaped. How can i achieve this?

Some code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory coDocFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder coDocBuilder = coDocFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
coXMLDocument = coDocBuilder.newDocument();

Element coParent = coXMLDocument.createElement("Parent");
coXMLDocument.appendChild(coParent);

Element coChild = coXMLDocument.createElement("Child");
coParent.appendChild(coChild);
coChild.setTextContent("<>/'/""); //apostrophe and quotes have been escaped

TransformerFactory coTransFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = coTransFactory.newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
DOMSource coDomSource = new DOMSource(coXMLDocument);
StreamResult coResult = new StreamResult(new File("C:\\a.xml"));
transformer.transform(coDomSource, coResult);
```

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this Apache library](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) to do it.